# Problems installing the INLA package

Tags: r, package, r-inla

When I run '''install.packages("INLA", repos=c(getOption("repos"), INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing"), dep=TRUE)''' keeps me giving this error:

Warning in install.packages :
cannot open URL 'https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/INLA_21.03.14-2.tgz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Why not try the stable version? `install.packages("INLA",repos=c(getOption("repos"),INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable"), dep=TRUE)`. It appears this URL ('https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/INLA_21.03.14-2.tgz') is incorrect. It should be pointing to `INLA_21.03.14-3.tgz` by the looks of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes,I tried but the download stops at a quarter with this error: Warning in install.packages: downloaded length 48332362 != reported length 185894595. Error in download.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're getting both network errors (`download length != reported length`) and installation errors of some sort.

I'd suggest trying to install the package from their `GitHub` repo directly like so (you'll need to install `devtools` beforehand for this).

```
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github(repo = "https://github.com/hrue/r-inla", ref = "stable", subdir = "rinla", build = FALSE)
```

I've tested this on a Unix-based machine, and it should work just fine.